# Advantage of Using Azure CDN

Tags: cdn, azure

We have a couple sites hosted on Azure's cloud, and we're using an external CDN for some content. Would there be any advantages in terms of performance if we were to use Azure's own CDN?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll get an answer without running tests on each CDN.

If by performance you mean page loading speed, then you can use http://www.webpagetest.org to test the exact same website behind each CDN, one CDN at a time, but make sure your whole server setup remains unchanged in both tests in order to get accurate results.

You may need to run the test again if the people running the CDN decide to upgrade the hardware since newer hardware is meant to provide better performance.

Comment: Hosting on the same network as the CDN would cut down a few ms but this can also be achieved by carefully studying the routes different CDN provide from each pop to where ever you host. My own opinion is that cutting 2-3ms in page loads is hardly a good reason. There are other criteria that are more important.